# reinterpret_cast vector of class A to vector of class B

Tags: c++, c++03

Say I have two classes `A` and `B`, and a vector of class `A` as below:

```
class A {
    int foo;
    int bar;
    void someMethod();
};
class B {
    uint foo;
    uint bar;
    void someOtherMethod();
};
std::vector<A>  va;
```

and I want to interpret `va` as a vector of B, since `int` and `uint` are re-interpretable.

What is the best practice to do the re-interpretation?
For example, if I want to invoke `someOtherMethod()` on `va`, I can do `((std::vector<B> *)(&va))->someOtherMethod()`.  But is it the best practice?

It seems to me that `reinterpret_cast<std::vector<B> >(va).someOtherMethod()` does NOT work.

In addition, I am working on C++03.

**-- UPDATE --**

Sorry for my misinterpret of my own question.
Yet my question will be a lot different than this one. So I created another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30843930/reinterpret-cast-vector-of-derived-class-to-vector-of-base-class).

I will close this question soon:  This question can be seen as an independent question, and I think one of the answers below is good enough to be accepted.

Comment: *`I have two classes`* - this is too broad. **Why** do you want to cast between them? (I'm guessing: one is "their" vector and one is "yours"?)

Comment: *"It seems to me that `reinterpret_cast<std::vector<B> >(va).someOtherMethod()` does NOT work."* - true, but you can use `reinterpret_cast<std::vector<unsigned>*>(&va)->someOtherMethod()` (with the same risk of undefined behaviour as your C-style cast notation).  Note that the risk isn't just from the layout of the types - there's also the question of aliasing - so your *" since int and uint are re-interpretable"* argument for the safety of this is faulty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't. Any way you think you can do it results in undefined behaviour. Create a new vector and copy over the values.

Answer (score 2):

The program behaviour is undefined since the types are unrelated.

One solution is to write a cast operator to copy a `class B` instance to a `class A` instance. In class `B`, write

```
operator A() const
{
    A a;
    a.foo = this->foo; // ToDo - check `this->foo` is an appropriate size
    a.bar = this->bar; // ToDo - check `this->bar` is an appropriate size
    return a; // compiler will elide the value copy
}
```

Comment: `the types are unrelated` exactly. This is one important case of misunderstood transitivity of class relationship.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get away with making a union type C which can be read as int or uint and making a vector of that instead.

```
union C {
    int s;
    uint u;
};

std::vector<C> va;
```

But that won't work if you need to pass it into a method that expects a `vector<uint>`.

In my opinion the right way to fix this is to make the method that expects a vector into a template so that it can accept any container type. Even better, make it like the STL methods and take an iterator or iterator pair.