# reinterpret_cast vector of derived class to vector of base class

Tags: c++, vector, c++03

I have a 3rd-party class, say, class `A`, and a function accepting vector of class `A` from the same 3rd-party, say `f3()` (See simplified program below).

For easier use of `A`, I created a derived class `B`.  Many part of my program used class `B`.

The question is, how can I call `f3()` with a vector of `B` as its argument?
Is a forced casting in the argument of `f3()` like the program below a good practice?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

// a 3rd-party class
class A
{
public:
    int n;
    void f1();
};

// my class
class B: public A
{
public:
    void f2();
};

// a 3rd-party function
void f3(std::vector<A> &a);

int main()
{
    std::vector<B> y;

    y.push_back(B());
    y.push_back(B());
    y.push_back(B());
    y.push_back(B());

    f3(*(vector<A>*)(&y));  // Is this a good practice?
    cout << y[3].n << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Note that, for compatibility, I purposely make class `B` to have no more variables than class `A`, when `B` inherits from `A`.  However, Class `B` does have more methods than `A`.

Will it guarantee that `sizeof(A)` is the same as `sizeof(B)`, so that our cast of vector will work?

I am working on C++03

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/30841015?

Comment: "f3(*(vector<A>*)(&y));  // Is this a good practice?" -- No it's undefined behaviour as far as I can tell. Although I've seen lots of 3rd party code doing this "trick". It always used to work but all bets are off.

Comment: No it's not guaranteed to work... it has undefined behaviour.  That said it may be reliable enough on your particular system - it's up to you to investigate and decide whether to accept the risk.  The issues are practically the same as your last - similar - question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30841015/reinterpret-cast-vector-of-class-a-to-vector-of-class-b).

Comment: A better question would be how can you get sufficient convenience for operations on `A`: non-member functions may help, you can still overload non-member operators if they're not provided with `A`, and a pointer- or reference-sporting wrapper class to an `A` can sometimes work pretty well. Some examples of the usage you want to support would help target the discussion.

Comment: If I test `sizeof(A)` and `sizeof(B)` to be the same in compile time, will the vectors be guaranteed to be compatible?

Comment: @RobinHsu ___No.___ You need to create a _new_ vector and copy the elements over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question from your code :

No, it's actually a very bad practice , and it will lead to undefined behavior.

If sizeof(A) is equal to sizeof(B) your code might end up working ,considering that all functions derived in B and used inside f3 are virtual and non inline.

If you end up using such code , make sure you will never ever add another virtual function / member variable to the B class .

If you want a way to bypass this limitation (f3 third party function only accepts vector of A ) , try making B a composite rather then a derived (if you are not accessing protected members of A ) :

```
class A 
{
   public:
   int n;
   void f1();
}
class B
{
  public:
      B (const A& a); // dependency injection
      void f2();
      A  myA; // bad practice, should be private with getter /setter
}
```

This way you are isolating the A specific functionality / features.

Ofc you will still need to manually make a vector of A objects made from the objects contained in B (you cannot pass a vector of B).

Comment: Yes, I plan to use B from A without any virtual functions, any more variables.  But why inline matters?   I think inline member functions mean  codes, not storage, and thus the vector should be compatible...

Comment: inline virtual functions might end up inlining from A . Also depending on what the function does behind, you might end up with slicing . This are general bad things that could happen if you use the approach you mentioned . You should test if what you proposed works fine for your project, but even if it does, you should keep in mind in the future why these approaches are bad.