# reinterpret_cast-ing vector of one type to a vector of another type which is of the same type

Tags: c++, vector, reinterpret-cast

I'm not sure if the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30841015/reinterpret-cast-vector-of-class-a-to-vector-of-class-b) answers this question due to the weird wording, but:

if i have:

```
struct numpair
{
    some_type_with_a_size_of_2 a,b;
};

struct bignum
{
    some_type_with_a_size_of_4 a;
};
```

Can I reinterpret_cast a vector of bignums to a vector of numpairs? If not, are there other workarounds that don't require me to make a new vector and go through reinterpret casting each element?

edit: on visual studio 2017 windows, which i am using, these two types are the same size.

edit: I have now learned if this strict aliasing rule. This is supposed to be binary data, viewed with different interfaces. Putting aside reinterpret_cast, could I possibly use a union of vectors of these types?

Comment: You absolutely cannot reinterpret_cast that. casting between two totally unrelated non-trivial types.... will not end well.

Comment: You can't even reinterpret_cast between a single `numpair` and `bignum`.

Comment: that's very, weird. I was sure you could. You aren't saying this because they have different sizes though, right? I know you can't do so with two differently sized classes.

Comment: Your very idea is completely and utterly broken. That would be true even if that wasn't a blatant violation of strict aliasing.

Comment: Why do you want to do it in the first place?

Comment: i need a common interface for two classes containing the same binary data, but that use it in different ways. I am sharing a vector of one type with another part of my program that shouldn't know that type with its interface. @NirFriedman

Comment: If it's supposed to represent binary data, then one of the types should be a char array, then it would be legal to cast, under certain circumstances. If the owner of the vector wants to allow the user to access the vector only as one of the representations but not the other, you have 3 options. The simplest is for the owner to actually store the vector as the type you want to expose, and cast internally. The second is for the owner to accept a lambda from the client to access the data. The third is to write your own iterators.

Comment: It might be better if you asked a new question, that gave some example code of what you are actually trying to accomplish, I can then write up the suggestions above more concrete. Feel free to tag me here with the link if that's what you decide to do.

Answer (score 3):

```
struct A
{
    int x;
};

struct B
{
    int x;
};
```

You can't even reinterpret cast between these two types. It would violate the strict aliasing rule. So no, you cannot do what you want.

> §3.10 Lvalues and rvalues [basic.lval]
>
> 10 If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object
>   through a glvalue of other than one of the following types the
>   behavior is undefined:<sup>54</sup>
>
> - the dynamic type of the object,
> - a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type similar (as defined in 4.4) to the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its elements or nonstatic data members (including,
>     recursively, an element or non-static data member of a subaggregate or
>     contained union),
> - a type that is a (possibly cv-qualified) base class type of the dynamic type of the object, — a char or unsigned char type.
>
> 54) The intent of this list is to specify those circumstances in which
>   an object may or may not be aliased.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat omg.cpp && g++ omg.cpp && echo ========== && ./a.out
#include <iostream>

struct numpair {
    unsigned short a,b;
};

struct bignum {
    unsigned long a;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << sizeof(numpair) << " != " << sizeof(bignum) << std::endl;
}
==========
4 != 8
```

Why do you think the types are the same?

Comment: when i ran this code i got:
4 != 4
Press any key to continue . . .
What operating system are you on?

Comment: @Evan You got "lucky". This happens to "work" on Windows, in the sense that the types happen to have the same size. It's still illegal though.

Comment: @BaummitAugen
yeah, I, for some reason, thought that long was guaranteed to be twice as long as short. At least I didn't learn it the hard way.

Comment: Invalid test - Obviously, `some_type_with_a_size_of_4` isn't `unsigned long` on your platform.

Comment: @immibis The question was edited in a way that invalidates the answer. Not bipll's fault.

Comment: @Evan `Linux 4.12.8-2-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Aug 18 14:08:02 UTC 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux` and `gcc version 7.1.1 20170630`, if you're curious. :)